# How does it look if I finish my PhD in five years instead of four?

Tags: phd, job-search, cv, early-career

I’m doing my PhD in computer science in Germany and next year would be my 4th (last) year. I can wrap it up until then, but I really like to have an extension to the 5th year. There are still 2–3 ideas that I have investigated but couldn’t finish because of the time frame, so I would like to do a bit more.

I have two publications so far and hopefully can have one more during the coming year, but I would like to have more publications, especially in better conferences. Also I think that I do not have yet enough expertise on the topic I’m working on.

Anyway, my supervisor prefers that I finish my PhD in four years, although I haven’t talked to him seriously about it yet. Also the funding would be available outside of his grant budget so he won’t be worried about it.

I’ve heard of many other students who finished in five or even six years, but I’m not sure in practice how important it could be especially if I can have good publications by extending my PhD.

Comment: Just a comment: if _next_ year will be your 4th this means you are now on your 3rd. Can't you wrap up in the next full year? 1 Year is usually enough if you are full time dedicated on research.

Comment: i need around 3 months for writing the dissertation and another 3 months waiting for reviewers to read it along with the disputation event. Also if next year is the last, then i need to start hunting for job or post-doc positions from now. So not much left to do new stuff, or to complete unfinished stuff. Just enough to wrap up what i've already done. That's my impression!

Comment: I am not sure I agree completely. The last year is, in most cases, the most productive even if at the same time you are awaiting for bureaucratic stuff like these you mention. One does not exclude the other.

Comment: I felt sheepish about taking 7.5 years to earn my MS/PhD when my husband only took 5, until we went to register for our marriage license. I asked the clerk what to put for "last grade completed" for a PhD; she said to just list the number of years of education, which gave me a higher total than my husband. If you stats about women more educated than their husbands, that includes me. :-)

Comment: Short answer: Nobody cares.

Comment: In the job market for academia, it is usually important to measure your publication record after the completion of your PhD. So papers after your degree are better than papers you did while doing your degree (specially if thye do not include your supervisor, which shows independence).

Comment: If you're going into the private sector, it's hard to imagine anyone caring.  The bigger issue is your career progression; you're giving up a year of career development and income to finish up whatever you're after in grad school.

Comment: It's relevant if you are in a field where you could continue your research with just time (math) or if you need equipment.

Comment: Honestly, as a fellow German academic, I don't have the slightest idea how long any one of my colleagues took. IMHO, @Superbest is right. At worst expect a question during your first PostDoc interview, but I would say even that is unlikely. 4 to 5 years isn't terribly long (in fact, the usual 3 year funding period is rather short; from my experience only a minority actually hands in their thesis within three years).

Comment: Some people extend their PhD studies just to have an additional year of research without any serious responsibilities or teaching load.

Comment: Only 5 years? Wow!!

Comment: A certain [Dr. Brian May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_May#Astrophysics) took 37 years to complete his thesis in Astrophysics. However, he did have rather a long sabbatical to pursue his other interests.

Comment: Oh my God! You're taking FIVE WHOLE YEARS! Just to complete a PhD?!?!? Get real - nobody will notice, or care. However, if there's no money for you to hang around for another year while padding your resume' I suggest you bow to reality and plan to finish in four.

Comment: Be aware: For sure there will be more than 2-3 unfinished ideas after the extension!

Comment: Why not? Enjoy it while it lasts

Comment: What do they call a guy who took five years to complete his PhD: *Doctor*

Comment: I had the opposite, finished in 3 years, rather than 4 - no one notices - the main thing is the PhD itself.

Comment: It looks like you have finished it in 5 years!

Comment: Andrew wiles also took 5 years.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The quality of your thesis overshadows the length/duration of your PhD.

Having said that, it depends on your goals. If you *clearly* think (and your adviser as well) that another year would make a big impact on the quality of your thesis and, consequently, on your CV, and is not too risky to pursue extra work (i.e., the questions you want to tackle are not too ambitious and you have a good possibility of enhancing your CV) *then* go for it. Otherwise, I am not sure you would want to stay at PhD while you could be looking for your next (PostDoc or industry) jobs.

Comment: i like the answer however i'm still in the dilemma of choosing between starting post-doc ASAP or completing PhD with better outcomes!

Comment: @Bob As I said, it really depends. If you think your current status can secure a good post-doc then go for it!

Comment: It also depends on your funding. If your advisor is not behind the idea of extending the timeframe, he might not be behind continuing to fund you either. I have heard of cases (in computer science in Germany), where advisors offered the student to keep the office, server use and whatever material they use on a day to day basis, but no TV-L salary. So a stipend or nothing it was.

Comment: @skymningen true, but I took it as a given, from the OP's question, that funding is not a problem.

Answer (score 15):

Finishing your PhD doesn't stop you from continuing in your field and creating additional publications. It is more likely people will look at your individual publications that at the contents of your thesis - but they *will* see that it took you five years.

If your department has funding to keep you after your defense, get the thesis wrapped up and keep publishing. It will look better.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the value of continuing to publish, although I disagree that people care how many years it took you to finish.

Comment: @EllenSpertus I didn't actually say that people cared. I said that they will see it... Some people may care - not everyone will. If you finish in four years, that is a non-issue; and it doesn't need to affect your over all academic output that you finish "on time".

Comment: Unfortunately, My supervisor doesn't have that funding for my post-doc position so i have to go somewhere else and it'd a far chance that i can directly continue my PhD topic.

Comment: @Bob You mean _fortunately_. Staying for PostDoc at the same place where you finished your PhD is not highly advisable.

Answer (score 12):

There are two separate questions that could be asked here:

1. Is it better or worse (or the same) to do a PhD in 5 years instead of 4?
2. How does it look to others viewing the CV of a person who does a PhD in 5 years instead of 4?

The first question is a perfectly reasonable question, and we can all imagine the cost/benefit factors that might go into answering it (it depends on a lot of factors).

But since the actual question being asked is #2, I'll ignore all of that cost/benefit analysis and say: basically, they look almost identical to others. In my experience, when people are being evaluated for the purposes of hiring (or promotion or awards), almost always the chronological datum that is used is "years since completion of the PhD". In that case, the number of years it takes to complete a PhD is (axiomatically) irrelevant.

Even if there is some tiny difference for the very first round of hiring, the quality of the letters of recommendation is far more important than the historical data on the CV.

Comment: This is true up to a point.  There's a joke that goes: How many graduate students does it take to change a light bulb?  One, but it takes him nine years.  (I did know someone who took nine years, without any interruptions or particular mishaps.  He was just plain slooow.)  But I do agree there's no functional difference (setting aside funding considerations) between *average length of PhD* and *average + 1*.

Comment: I'm going to agree but disagree. I agree that the datum which is used is almost always "years since completion of Ph. D." Therefore, if you are going to produce the same amount of research in the optional year either way, you should remain in grad school longer, so you will be viewed as a person with that much research k years after Ph. D rather than the same amount k+1 years after Ph. D.

Answer (score 9):

> **Q:** What do you call someone who finished their Ph.D. after five years instead of four?
>
> **A:** A Ph.D.

Enough said.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your next goal.

## If you want to stay in academia

If you want to stay in academia, **do it.** The quality of your papers and your dissertation are very important, and an additional year with good results might certainly be worth it.

## If you want to get a job in the industry

If you want to get a job in the industry, **don't do it**. The additional year is going to hurt your CV and delay the moment until you get a proper income even more.

Comment: Your claim that 5 rather than 4 years of PhD time hurts your CV is, in my experience and that of people I know, quite unfounded.

Comment: @einpoklum: the point is for purposes of working in industry, your CV after 4 years PhD **and** 1 year working will be much better than your CV after 5 years and 0 years working.

Comment: @TomChurch: Well, your CV after a 3-year PhD and 2 years in industry would be even better... more seriously, though, if the answer said "for working in industry, additional publications in an extra year of a PhD are not nearly as useful on a CV than a year of work experience", that would be something else altogether (Although for getting that 1-year position you still have to make do with the PhD-only CV, so it's not really a fair comparison).

Comment: @einpoklum The student will be one year older with no 'real' work experience. Being a year younger and not having to explain why he needed an extra year for his phd at the interview is a bonus, while people most likely won't care about the 'great papers' done in the additional year.

Comment: @Wilbert: (1) You're making the wrong comparison. We're talking about a PhD with no industry experience in both cases; the difference is 4 or 5 years to finish. (2) You're assuming what you're trying to demonstrate, which is that a 5-year PhD is something problematic which needs explanation. Again, from my experience and that of more than a few freinds and acquaintance of mine - it does not.

Comment: @einpoklum (1) All things equal industry people would pick the younger candidate with the shorter phd against someone with identical credentials but older + longer phd (2) I'm not assuming it, I had to a) explain the duration of my own phd in my job interviews, and b) I have asked candidates with longer phds for an explanation when they interviewed for positions with me. I just cannot agree that one more year doesn't matter. It does, since you are competing with lots and lots of other people.

Comment: @Wilbert: (1) You keep making the same assertion again and again. It's not true. Or at least, it's not true in my surroundings, and I believe your example is the exception rather than the rule. Not to mention the fact that the company doesn't even know how old you are. (2) The fact that this happened to you doesn't mean it's universal or even very common. No PhD, or interviewer I know has ever asked or been asked that question. I think that's the general rule - although, to be frank, I don't have any statistics or anything to back up this impression, just anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @einpoklum Both of our personal experiences are just 'anecdotal evidence'. So lets focus on the lost year. At least here in europe, you won't even get invited to an interview for a good job if you don't have your complete cv (including dob and everything). So the company knows very well how old you are, and will use that as a criteria. And one year more for the same credentials (PhD) is a negative.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might look a way "special" for some people and they can end up with some (probably wrong) assumptions about you if your education/research years happen to deviate from what is considered the common norm.

But I'd recommend to just opt-out of being a part of the world of stereotypes, prejudice and "magical thinking" kind of judgement and take (if offered) as much time as you need to make the research you want with adequate quality and with a fair amount of joy.

I believe that whoever whose opinion is going to be relevant to your further career will probably bother finding out the reason of the deviation (if interested at all) and respect the decision to take somewhat more time for a better job over choosing mediocrity just to fit in the common time frame (if the reason for the delay is something other than above-average quality (or a serious sickness or something like that) though, I'd recommend to invest some effort and make it at least somewhat above-average however).

Under "quality" I mean all the things that evaluate a research paper: how interesting, important, unexplored and hard-to-explore the subject is, how comprehensive your research is, how well-defined, well-verified and easily-applicable your result are, how well-written the actual paper is etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to continue your life in academia (become a professor or a senior scientist), then it doesn't matter, because you'll seek a postdoc job next, which will only be different by contract type and the money you get (I assume you get 50%, or at best 75%, of a position now? that's the average to best in Germany... I've been there).

If you're planning to go to industry and leave academia, then I don't know how much to emphasize that you should finish as soon as possible. A company mostly doesn't give a damn about your PhD thesis or publications as much as that you have a PhD title from a university. ***All*** that a company cares about is your skills and age. Other than your skills, primarily, nothing matters! It's very unlikely that you'll gain new production relevant skills by staying another year (you may become a better researcher though). So I would recommend that you get out and start your serious career (again, in case you don't want to continue in academia).

Answer (score 0):

I finished my PhD in five years instead of four. I knew I would leave academics afterwards and my fifth year was combined with my first year in industry. It was tough but did not impact the slightest my future career (in the sense that it was 5y and not 4). A fellow of mine did the same thing.

I then hired over the years a few PhD in the company I was working in and I never checked how long it took them to get the grade. The fact that they had it was rather an indication of character/orientation than ability/fitness for work.

Finally, you mention that your PhD is in Germany. I do not know if you intend to stay there afterwards but a PhD is **immensely** positive (prestigious) and, by all means, get it (even if it not of that much use afterwards - like in my case).